# ReactJS Redux state persisting after being reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Basically I got a state called `optimizer` in which I store a field named `optimizer_course_entries` , this field has 2 reducers on it:

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    optimizer_course_entries : [],
}

export const optimizerSlice = createSlice(
    {
        name: 'optimizer',
        initialState,
        reducers: {
            edit_entry: (state, action) => {
                console.log('CALLED EDIT REDUCERS');
                state.optimizer_course_entries[action.payload.index] = action.payload.value;
            },
            reset: (state) => {
                console.log('CALLED RESET REDUCER');
                state.optimizer_course_entries = [];
            }

        }
    }
)

export const {edit_entry, reset} = optimizerSlice.actions;

export default optimizerSlice.reducer;
```

In my react app, I have a call to edit_entry everything a textbox is edited, and it sends the index and value in a payload to Redux.

```js
  const receiveChange = (Value, Index) => {

    dispatch(edit_entry({
        index : Index,
        value : Value,
      }));
  }
```

I have the reset reducer set on component mount like this:

```js
    React.useEffect(
    () => {

      dispatch(reset());

    } , [] 
  )
```

The issue i'm having is that on component mount, instead of redux only doing a reset, it also restores previous reducer actions..

[image: issue]

And in my redux store, the `optimizer_course_entries` entry is identical to before the reset...

I'm still pretty new to redux, is there a way I can specify it so that upon re-mount it doesn't do this repopulation?

Comment: It restores it? Are you sure there isn't another part of the component or codebase that are dispatching these actions?

Comment: Nvm, it was the chrome extension that I was using that was doing some weird state persisting `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/`, do you can you recommend any good redux dev tools extensions? this one isn't the best

Comment: That extension is the de facto debugging tool for redux. Try looking into the settings of the extension to see if you can disable the behavior you're trying to stop